# Dynamic loading Firestore and RecyclerView

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection X in my firestore database and I'm gonna display it as RecyclerView by using FirestoreRecyclerAdapter or just an ordinary RecyclerAdapter(doesn't matter). So, you know that in YouTube comments are being loaded dynamically. Every time you get to the bottom of comments YouTube starts loading new comments. Cause of Firestore billing it's not effective to load all documents in collection at once. Also would be great if you tell me how exactly queries work in FirestoreRecyclerAdapter.

Comment: If you are interested in a Firestore real-time pagination algorithm you can tale a look this [example](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirestoreRealtimePagination), which is a repo for this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-a-clean-firestore-pagination-with-real-time-updates-ce05a87bb902).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're describing is known as "infinite scroll" and also commonly referred to as pagination.

If you search for the topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-cloud-firestore%5D+pagination) you'll get many previous questions that deal with it. FirebaseUI also has an [adapter that support pagination](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/firestore#using-the-firestorepagingadapter), although only with Firestore's non-realtime data retrieval.

Comment: Thanks bro) I didn't know that it's named pagination and now I just searched for it on YouTube.